# How to interact with my play application in console?

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt, ammonite

I have a play 2.8.x application that uses scala.

The sbt project has a play web project and another library module.

Is it possible to interact with the other module in a REPL?
I have ammonite installed on my system also, but not sure how to load my module.  Do I just have to build and then reference the library in my /target build folder? Or is there a better way?

Can I do this in sbt by itself or ammonite is the only way?

Answer (score 1):

Every sbt project has a REPL, you just have to run:

```
sbt> console
```

for root project or for `name` project

```
sbt> name/console
```

But this is normal Scala REPL, if you want ammonite, then [there is instruction on ammonite.io](http://ammonite.io/#Ammonite-REPL):

> You can also try out Ammonite 2.1.4 in an existing SBT project. To do so, add the following to your build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += {
  val version = scalaBinaryVersion.value match {
    case "2.10" => "1.0.3"
    case _ ⇒ "2.1.4"
  }
  "com.lihaoyi" % "ammonite" % version % "test" cross CrossVersion.full
}

sourceGenerators in Test += Def.task {
  val file = (sourceManaged in Test).value / "amm.scala"
  IO.write(file, """object amm extends App { ammonite.Main.main(args) }""")
  Seq(file)
}.taskValue

// Optional, required for the `source` command to work
(fullClasspath in Test) ++= {
  (updateClassifiers in Test).value
    .configurations
    .find(_.configuration.name == Test.name)
    .get
    .modules
    .flatMap(_.artifacts)
    .collect{case (a, f) if a.classifier == Some("sources") => f}
}
```

> After that, simply hit

```
sbt projectName/test:run
```

> or if there are other main methods in the Test scope

```
sbt projectName/test:run-main amm
```